# nestjs & mongoose - issues returning a promise after updating collection

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have those schemas:

A Foo collection that has a one-to-many relationship to Bar:

```
@Schema()
export class Foo {
  @Prop()
  attr1: number;
  @Prop({ type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Bar' })
  bar: Bar;
}
export const FooSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Foo);

@Schema()
export class Bar {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  firstName: string;
  @Prop([{ type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Foo.name }])
  foos: Foo[];
}
export const BarSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Bar);
```

I'm trying to save a new Foo in my Mongodb using Mongoose, with nestjs. In my foo.service.ts, I have this:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Foo.name) private fooModel: Model<FooDocument>,
    @InjectModel(Bar.name) private barModel: Model<BarDocument>,
  ) {}

  // this works but doesn't save the related foos in Bar.foos[]
  // async create(foo: Foo): Promise<Foo> {
  //   const newFoo = new this.fooModel(foo);
  //   return await foo.save();
  // }

  async create(foo: Foo): Promise<Bar> {
    const newFoo = new this.fooModel(foo);
    const savedFoo = newFoo.save().then(function (f) {
      return this.barModel.findByIdAndUpdate(f._id, {
        $push: { foos: f._id },
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I know that my first method (the commented out one) works and the schema is saved correctly, because in my Foo class on Mongo I see the ObjectId reference to the proper Bar object in D. However, Bar.foo array remains empty. I seem to understand that in Mongo, I need to push the reference of my new Foo object that I just saved into the Bar.foo array. So I am retrieving the corresponding Bar object with mongoose, update it by pushing the foo._id.

But I get:

```
- error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

Before the server even starts.... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statement in this function, since you declared the return type for it must be `Promise<Bar>`

```
async create(foo: Foo): Promise<Bar> {
    const newFoo = new this.fooModel(foo);
    const savedFoo = newFoo.save().then(function (f) {
      return this.barModel.findByIdAndUpdate(f._id, {
        $push: { foos: f._id },
      });
    });
  }
```